# How does this derivative substitution work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, substitution

I'm trying to understand a proof from [this paper on the SIR model.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2160.pdf) This appears at the bottom of page four.

The following two equations are given:

> $ u\frac{d^2u}{dt^2} - (\frac{du}{dt})^2 + (\gamma - x_0\beta u)u\frac{du}{dt} = 0 \quad \mathbf{(22)}$
>
> $ \phi = \frac{dt}{du} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\; \mathbf{(23)}$

The next part is where I am having trouble. It reads:

> *With the help of the transformation given by Eq. **(23)**, Eq. **(22)** becomes a Bernoulli type differential equation,*
>
> $$ \frac{d\phi}{du} + \frac{1}{u}\phi = (\gamma - x_0\beta u)\phi^2 \quad \mathbf{(24)}$$

How is this possible? I can't seem to work it out. Please show me how equations **(22)** and **(24)** are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have:
$$\frac {du}{dt}=\frac 1 {\phi}$$
Therefore:
$$\frac {d^2u}{dt^2}=\frac {d}{dt}\frac 1 {\phi}= \left (\frac {d}{du}\frac 1 {\phi} \right )\frac {du}{dt}$$
$$\frac {d^2u}{dt^2}=\frac 1 {\phi}\left (\frac {d}{d \phi}\frac 1 {\phi} \right)\frac {d\phi}{du}$$
$$\frac {d^2u}{dt^2}=\frac 1 {\phi} \left(-\frac 1 {\phi ^2} \right)\frac {d\phi}{du}$$
$$\frac {d^2u}{dt^2}=-\frac 1 {\phi^3}\frac {d\phi}{du}  \text { and } \frac {du}{dt}=\frac 1 {\phi}$$

Substitute that in your original equation :
$$u\frac{d^2u}{dt^2} - (\frac{du}{dt})^2 + (\gamma - x_0\beta u)u\frac{du}{dt} = 0 $$
The equation becomes:
$$\frac{d\phi}{du} + \frac{1}{u}\phi - (\gamma - x_0\beta u)\phi^2=0 $$

Comment: Wow, thank you! I've always been confused about the rules surrounding when and why you can treat an expression like $\frac{du}{dt}$ as a fraction. Is that always possible? I feel as though many of my math teachers have insisted that is not the case.

Comment: You're welcomed. it's not the case indeed but here  i used the fact that $\phi$ is considered as a function of $u$ @cole_theman